# Not able programmatically select value in angular-bootstrap-select plugin

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

For some reason select control ignores changes of it's model after initialization.
This is my controller:

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.data = ["Admin","Manager","User"];    
   $scope.selectedRole = "Admin";    

   $scope.btnClick = function() {        
      $scope.selectedRole = "User";        
   }; 
});
```

As you can see initially I set default value to "Admin" which is work perfectly fine. Then I'm trying to change value to "User" on button click and this part doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/seahawk/qzL4jft7/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, but you're missing the angular-bootstrap file. The files you need are:

- bootstrap.min.css
- angular.js
- ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxjc8eda/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select) angular-bootstrap-select plugin requires only jquery, bootstrap-select and angular. In your fiddle you are using UI Bootstrap, but unfortunatelly I have to work with existing bootstrap template.

Comment: @AlexK UI Bootstrap is the recommended way of using bootstrap with angular, http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. It's still using the existing bootstrap template.